# Angular-UI Bootstrap Collapse without animation

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to deactivate the animation of [Collapse](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) ?

My problem with the animation is that there's always one active and the rest collapsed,
so I don't want every element under to move (even if it's for a couple seconds).
Or if possible just a "fade" animation. But not a "pop from under".

Answer (score 6):

Using version 0.12.1, overriding the animation duration on the `collapsing` class with a small value worked for me:

*HTML*

```
<div class="your-class" collapse="collapsed">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.your-class.collapsing {
    transition-duration: 0.0125s;
}
```

Setting the duration value to `0` did not work as it caused the element to remain in `collapsing` state indefinitely.

---

**Update**

While the solution described above worked fine, I ended up just using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` to get rid of the unwanted animation altogether.

Comment: I had luck simply setting `.your-class.collapsing { transition: none; }`  (Angular 1.4.5, Angular-Bootstrap 0.13.4)

Answer (score 0):

The [Collapse](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.js) directive uses the [Transition](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/transition/transition.js) directive to perform the animations.  There does not appear to be an option to specify the type of transition. The collapse directive looks pretty straight forward though, so you should be able to use that as a starter for writing a new directive with the animation you want.  Or you could submit an enhancement request to add that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify **new class** for your **element** and /or his **parent** and then set new transition to **parent child / element with new class**:

```
transition: all 0 ease 0;
```

This is default value from W3C.
If this will not help try to set rule as !important;